# how to update root data in vue router beforeEach

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I am working on VueJS2 with the Vue router app. I can access root data from the router instance `console.log(router.app.authorized) or console.log('router', router.app.$root.authorized)` beforeEach hook. But I need to update root data from beforeEach instance.
when I update this code like e.g: `router.app.authorized = true or router.app.$root.authorized = true`
can't update root data.
Maybe my approach is totally wrong or mistakes something. In this case how to solve this issue

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself preferably in a Stack Snippet. See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

this is my code,it worked for me.

```
// define router
const createRouter = () => new Router({
  routes: constantRoutes,
  isAddDynamicMenuRoutes: false
})
```

```
// beforeEach 
if (router.options.isAddDynamicMenuRoutes) {
  next()
} else {
  router.options.isAddDynamicMenuRoutes = true
  ...
  next({ ...to, replace: true })
}
```

Comment: But I want to update $root.$data in my code. When updating in router beforeEach instance router page console show updated data but when seeing VueDevTool root data then can see can't update.